# Java how to put a dot after a period

Tags: java, regex

I have a piece of text. What i want to do is that in the entire text i want to put a whitespace after all the periods if its not already present. If its already present i dont want two spaces.

Also if the text contains multiple consecutive periods i want to put a whitespace only after the last period and that too only if whitespace is not already present.

I tried using this:

```
.replaceAll("[.!?;]", "$0 ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
```

But this fails for multiple dots

Thanks.

Comment: When you [post a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44418931/62576) and it gets downvoted for poor quality, it is not acceptable to delete it and immediately post it again in the same exact form. Instead, edit your previous question to improve it. Posting the same poor question that gets downvoted and close votes, deleting it and posting the same question again will only lead to more downvotes and close votes, and repeating that behavior over and over again will get your account here suspended.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/2891664 for more info on what Ken is talking about. Deleting your downvoted question and reposting it is actually worse than just fixing the downvoted question, because deleted questions are included when considering question bans.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to place a space after dot if it is not there:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\.(?![.\\s])", "$0 ");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zORjDg/1)

`(?![.\\s])` is a negative lookahead that will assert false if next position has a whitespace or dot characters.

Answer (score 0):

The part about *unless a whitespace is already present* is a moot point.
Generally, for the quickest solution, suck up all the data with a pattern,
blindly then replace it.

https://regex101.com/r/aPa0Bk/1

Globally,
Find `(?:\s+|(\.+))\s*`
Replace `'$1 '`

This is designed to trim whitespace as it goes.